The simplest example where stable matching does not exist?
I heard that the stable matching of a roomate problem might not exist.
My question is, what is a simple example illustrating the non-existence, and if there is simpler matching problem where stable matching does not exist?

Consider three individuals with preferences $\succ_1, \succ_2$ and $\succ_3$.
Consider the following preferences (for matchings)
$$
\begin{align*}
&2 \succ_1 3 \succ_1 \emptyset\\
&3 \succ_2 1 \succ_2 \emptyset\\
&1 \succ_3 2 \succ_3 \emptyset.
\end{align*}
$$
Here $\emptyset$ is the situation where the individual is not matched.

If 1 is matched with 2, the couple (2,3) forms a blocking pair.
If 1 is matched with 3, the couple (1,2) forms a blocking pair.
If 2 is matched with 3, the couple (1,3) forms a blocking pair.

